# What is the best pattern for a static class with an unmanaged static instance?

Tags: c#

Consider the following pseudo code.

```
static class Tools
{
    static readonly UnmanagedType ut = new UnmanagedType ();
}
```

What is the best pattern for this scenario such that the unmanaged static instance can be guaranteed to get released to the system right after the application exits?

My rough idea is to compulsorily subscribe `Tools` disposing method to the system's close event right after `ut` is instantiated in `Tools` class. Is it possible? How?

Comment: This is not necessary, and object referenced by a static variable gets finalized at program exit.  How an "unmanaged type" could be instantiated with the *new* operator is very murky.  If that code works then it can also have a finalizer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Singleton?

```
sealed class Tools
{
    public static readonly Tools Instance = new Tools();

    private UnmanagedType ut = new UnmanagedType ();

    ~Tools() {
      // TODO: destroy this.ut
    }
}
```

Comment: But it is not a static class. :-)

Comment: Yes, I intentionally removed it because static class cannot have destructors.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen several answers to the similar questions (i.e. “How to release/dispose objects/resources in static class once a process exits”). All the answers basically state that 
a)  static class in C# cannot have destructor (which is correct),
b)  and therefore you cannot release resources at the end of static class life,
c)  hence you MUST turn your class to non-static to dispose/release objects/resources.

I disagree with the items b) and c) and suggest the following solution for disposing the objects in static class on exit:

1. In your static class constructor or any first call to its method that creates the object(s) to dispose:

   a) save a main process thread reference (`Thread.CurrentThread`);
   b) start a new thread (**Watcher**) that monitors whether the main thread is running.
2. Once the main thread dies, the **Watcher** disposes/releases the objects/resources and exits.

Example code:

```
using System.Threading;

public static class StaticDisposer 
{
    private static Thread mParentProcThread = null;
    private static Thread mDisposerThread = null;
  // Other class members:
        ………………………………………………

  // Objects to be disposed at the process exit:
  // Ex.: private/public static … obj1ToDispose = null;
        ………………………………………………

    static StaticDisposer()
    {
         mParentProcThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
         mDisposerThread = new Thread(DisposerThreadBody);
         mDisposerThread.Start();
    }

  // Methods of the class:
        ………………………………………………

    private static void DisposerThreadBody()
    {
        while (mParentProcThread != null && mParentProcThread.IsAlive)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        // Dispose objects, release resources, close streams, delete temporary files, etc.:
        //if(obj1ToDispose != null)
        //    <Dispose code>
        //   ………………………………………………………………………………
    }

}
```

**NB!** If you have several threads in your program that are using your static class with the suggested disposing logic and you want the disposing to happen only when the main thread stops, then the main thread MUST call/set/get any method/property of the static class before the secondary threads do.